# Map in React JSX causes Uncaught Invariant Violation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a component which displays breadcrumbs:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Breadcrumb} from 'antd';
import {BreadcrumbItem} from '../../models/BreadcrumbItem';

  interface Props {
    trail: BreadcrumbItem[]
  }

class Breadcrumbs extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {

        console.log('this.props.trail is ', this.props.trail);

        return (
            <>
                {this.props.trail && (
                    <Breadcrumb>
                        <Breadcrumb.Item>
                            <a href="">Home</a>
                        </Breadcrumb.Item>
                        {this.props.trail.map((t: BreadcrumbItem) => {
                            return <Breadcrumb.Item>
                                    <a href={t.address}>{t.name}</a>
                                </Breadcrumb.Item>
                        })};
                    </Breadcrumb>
                )}
            </>
        );
    }

}


export {Breadcrumbs};
```

`Breadcrumb` and `Breadcrumb.Item` are [Ant Design components](https://ant.design/components/breadcrumb/)

`BreadcrumbItem` is my own model defined as:

```
export interface BreadcrumbItem {
    name: string;
    address: string;
  }
```

And in the parent component:

```
let breadcrumbTrail: BreadcrumbItem[] = [];

const breadcrumbItem : BreadcrumbItem = {
  name: 'Orders',
  address: '/orders'
};

breadcrumbTrail.push(breadcrumbItem);

....

return (
   <>
     <Breadcrumbs trail={breadcrumbTrail} />
   </>
);
```

But I end up with the error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

If I comment out the `map()` in the Breadcrumbs component, the error disappears and the breadcrumbs display.

### EDIT

As suggested by @Muhammad Zeeshan, I'm now wxporting using `default`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Breadcrumb} from 'antd';
import {BreadcrumbItem} from '../../models/BreadcrumbItem';

interface Props {
    trail: BreadcrumbItem[]
}

class Breadcrumbs extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {

        console.log('this.props.trail is ', this.props.trail);

        return (
            <>
                {this.props.trail && (
                    <Breadcrumb>
                        <Breadcrumb.Item>
                            <a href="">Home</a>
                        </Breadcrumb.Item>
                        {this.props.trail.map((t: BreadcrumbItem) => {
                            return <Breadcrumb.Item>
                                    <a href={t.address}>{t.name}</a>
                                </Breadcrumb.Item>
                        })};
                    </Breadcrumb>
                )}
            </>
        );
    }

}


export default Breadcrumbs;
```

And importing:

```
import Breadcrumbs from '../Breadcrumbs/Breadcrumbs';
```

But getting the error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Along with the Warning:

```
index.js:1 Warning: [antd: Breadcrumb] Only accepts Breadcrumb.Item and Breadcrumb.Separator as it's children
```

Again, once I comment out the map(), it works and displays....

Comment: adding a code sandbox example would help debug

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your export statement from:

```
export {Breadcrumbs};
```

to

```
export default Breadcrumbs;
```

Comment: Edited the question there, still have issues